# Errors uploading CodeIgniter Website to Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, codeigniter

I tried to transfer my CodeIgniter website to `/var/www/html` located within my Amazon EC2 micro instance using FileZilla. However, the transfer was unsuccessful as I received hundreds of transfer errors while attempting to transfer my CodeIgniter website.

My question is, how do I upload my CodeIgniter website to `/var/www/html` ?

---

The results of `sudo ls -l /var/www` are:

> drwxrwxrw- 2 root root 4096 Apr 30 22:54 cgi-bin 
>   drwxrwxrw- 3 root root 4096 May 22 12:25 error 
>   drwxrwxrw- 2 root root 4096 Jan  6  2012 html
>   drwxrwxrw- 3 root root 4096 May 22 12:25 ic

Comment: What exactly are you getting for errors?

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply Nathan. I got permission errors: "/var/www/html/test.txt: open for write: permission denied Error: File transfer failed"

Comment: I used FileZilla to drag and drop my website to that location.

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. I'll write up some instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, ec2-user (the default Amazon AMI user) lacks permissions to the /var/www directory. To fix it, use:

`usermod -a -G www-data ec2-user`

This will add your ec2-user to apache's group so you can make the edits. Root is unable to log in via SSH by default (this can be adjusted, though) so this will work as a workaround. If the apache user is different, change `www-data` to the appropriate user.

Comment: +1 Thanks Nathan. Regarding the Apache user, how do I find that info? The following answer suggested this command: ps aux | grep apache but when I tried it, I see several rows with "apache" (and 1 with ec2-user) with several columns of numbers, question marks, data and /usr/sbin/httpd directory. I did not see apache user.   (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as)

Comment: In `ps aux`, the user is the first column. Look for a line that shows `/usr/sbin/httpd` and the first column will have the name of the user. Typical names are "apache2", "apache", or "www-data".

Comment: I forgot to first mention that when I tried "sudo usermod -a -G www-data ec2-user", I got this message: "usermod: group 'www-data' does not exist".

Comment: That's probably because the apache user is different. :-)

Comment: When I entered "sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user", it just returned to the prompt with no errors. However, when I tried to transfer my test file to /var/www/html , I got the same errors:  "Error: /var/www/html/test.txt: open for write: permission denied Error: File transfer failed".

Comment: I was transferring test.txt using FileZilla

Comment: Ohh, do I have to restart apache?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to. Try this: `chmod -R 776 /var/www`. This should put the permissions as they should be.

Comment: Running "sudo chmod -R 776 /var/www" produced no errors (is it supposed to be /var/www/http ?). However, I tried to transfer the test.txt file to /var/www/http and got the same errors for /var/www. I tried to access /var/www using putty, but got the following error: "var/www: Permission denied". But the strangest thing I noticed is, my http directory disappeared from within the FileZilla "Remote site" window.

Comment: Hm, your permissions are screwed up it looks like. Can you update your question with the output of `ls -l /var/www`?

Comment: "ls -l /var/www" displayed this: drwxrwxrw- 2 root root 4096 Apr 30 22:54 cgi-bin
drwxrwxrw- 3 root root 4096 May 22 12:25 error
drwxrwxrw- 2 root root 4096 Jan  6  2012 html
drwxrwxrw- 3 root root 4096 May 22 12:25 ic

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll update my question, now rereading your answer!

Comment: I see, they're all owned by root. Type `chown -R apache:apache /var/www` to replace with the proper owner, where `apache` is your httpd's user. That'd by why it wasn't working :-)

Comment: +1 Yay! Yes it worked!

Comment: Thanks a lot Nathan. You've been very helpful. I'll research every single command you've given me inorder to understand and master this. Thanks a whole lot!