# Blank CodeIgniter Home Page on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, codeigniter

My CodeIgniter app is working fine in WAMP using `http://localhost/myapp`

However, I'm getting a blank page on my Amazon EC2 micro instance using `http://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/myapp` .

Also, I still get the Amazon Linux AMI Test page using this link: (I commented out contents of welcome.conf): `http://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

My question is: what changes do I need to make in order to get my CodeIgniter application to work on my EC2 micro instance? My application does not use a database. It just queries the Twitter API and returns the results.

Here is what I've done so far:

1. I uploaded [my CodeIgniter app](https://serverfault.com/questions/510203/errors-uploading-codeigniter-website-to-amazon-ec2) to the `/var/www/html` directory of my Amazon EC2 micro instance with no errors using FileZilla.
2. I also tried to disable the Amazon Linux AMI Test page by commenting out the following lines in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`

> LocationMatch "^/+$"
>   Options -Indexes
>   Errordocument 403 /error/noindex.html
>   /LocationMatch

**EDIT 1**
In my CodeIgniter root directory, I have a .htaccess file (see below). Do I have to do a similar configuration in my EC2 instance inorder to access my CI home page?:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /myapp

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: is your apache is compiled with PHP support on your micro instance?

Comment: Check `/var/log/httpd/error.log`.

Comment: @AbhishekAnandAmralkar If he's editing `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`, he's using Apache, not nginx.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have corrected my comment.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply @ceejayoz. I tried to access `/var/log/httpd/error.log` but I got a "Permission Denied" error. When I ran: `sudo ls -l httpd/` I got this: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root ... error_log` I am ec2-user. How should I change this to access the error?

Comment: `sudo tail /var/log/httpd/error_log` will show you the last few lines of that file.

Comment: +1 I got `Digest: done.` followed by this line 8 times:  `...error ... File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico...`

Comment: Closing this question is unfortunate. I'm so close to getting my application working.

Answer (score 1):

Put below lines in the httpd.conf

```
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

and restart apache afterward

Fond out below line in apache config

```
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

make it

```
  Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

This will disable directory listing under your apache.

Comment: If he's getting a blank page (and not raw PHP source code), PHP is likely to be properly enabled, and he's just getting a 500 error due to some sort of misconfiguration.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for your reply Abhishek. I entered the lines in the httpd.conf and restarted Apache (sudo httpd -k restart). Unfortunately, the page is still blank using `http://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/myapp`. Interesting though, I'm not getting the Amazon AMI Test Page from `http://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/` anymore. I'm getting an "Index of" page which displays my "myapp" folder. When I open it, the page is blank.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: +1 Thanks Abhishek. It worked. I'm now getting a Permission Denied message from `http://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/` However, see EDIT 1 in my question above. I've included the .htaccess file thats in my CodeIgniter root directory and was wondering if I have to do something similar in EC2 in order to display my application using `http://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/myapp`.